# Is there any way to scrape LinkedIn link from different websites using BeautifulSoup or Selenium in jupyter notepad python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to store some of website's social media LinkedIn link or you can say to **scrape** LinkedIn link (if any) of different websites using BeautifulSoup or Selenium in python.
I have tried scraping LinkedIn link for a particular website (if it has any) but this isn't generic, since all websites have different variable for storing LinkedIn List.
Note: this is education and learning purpose.
Example of a website having LinkedIn link in them is attached in pictures. In case any website hasn't LinkedIn , just store "-".
I hope there is a way.
Thanks for your kind attention.
[image]

Comment: I want an automated python program to fetch particular website's LinkedIn link present inside that website. Link may after be changed to another website but program must be independent of link and should fetch linkedIn link . Waiting for your help and kind response. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've used this github repo to do the same on Google Images. Perhaps there is not much to change: https://github.com/WuLC/GoogleImagesDownloader

Comment: Thanks for reply. However this is not what I want. I want an automated python program to fetch particular website's LinkedIn link present inside that website.